# "tfx login" sits indefinitely

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm doing a POC in which I need to create a custom VSTS release step.  Documentation I have found has pointed me to using Powershell and TFX (TFS Cross Platform Command Line Interface).  However, when I try to log into my VSTS instance using "tfx login", I see the following and then it just sits... forever.

```
PS C:\Users\mmulhe200> tfx
TFS Cross Platform Command Line Interface v0.3.30
Copyright Microsoft Corporation

                        fTfs         
                      fSSSSSSSs      
                    fSSSSSSSSSS      
     TSSf         fSSSSSSSSSSSS      
     SSSSSF     fSSSSSSST SSSSS      
     SSfSSSSSsfSSSSSSSt   SSSSS      
     SS  tSSSSSSSSSs      SSSSS      
     SS   fSSSSSSST       SSSSS      
     SS fSSSSSFSSSSSSf    SSSSS      
     SSSSSST    FSSSSSSFt SSSSS      
     SSSSt        FSSSSSSSSSSSS      
                    FSSSSSSSSSS      
                       FSSSSSSs      
                        FSFs    (TM) 

Available commands and command groups in tfx:
 - login: Login and cache credentials using a PAT or basic auth.
 - version: Output the version of this tool.
 - reset: Reset any saved options to their defaults.
 - logout: Log out and clear cached credential.
 - workitem: Commands for managing Work Items.
 - build: Commands for managing Builds.
 - extension: Commands to package, publish, and manage Extensions for Visual Studio Team Services.


For help with an individual command, type tfx  <command> --help


PS C:\Users\mmulhe200> tfx login
TFS Cross Platform Command Line Interface v0.3.30
Copyright Microsoft Corporation
```

Anyone have any insight in what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Switching over to Developer Command Prompt for VS2015, the login command started to work.